# Customizing UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller

I need to change font size and background color of the list displayed by "More" button of the UITabBarController. Is it possible ? How can I do it ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean?
Do you have a tab bar controller application with a button called "More"?

Comment: Yes, I have tab bar with lot of pages (about 20). I mean when user touch "More" button -- table with list of extra pages appears. I want to change cell's font and background color in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has a property called `moreNavigationController`, the root view of which is presumably the `UITableView` you see when you tap the "More" button.

If you want to customize the table view cells, you'll need to reassign its `dataSource` to an object you control. But, you'll need to implement every method of `UITableViewDataSource` and forward those messages to the original data source.

In your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you'll be able to customize the cell returned by the original data source's implementation of that method.

Sounds like a lot of work just to change some fonts, doesn't it?

Comment: That's right. Lots of work. But I'm familiar with table cells so it's no problem for me. Thanks a lot for point on moreNavigationController root view. I missed it :)